# Pygame: game displays nothing, despite 'while' loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Im working on a simple game( a semi copy of the 'Dodger' game), and the game runs, yet displays nothing. I have a while loop running, so why is nothing showing up?  Is it a problem with spacing, the images themselves, or am i just overlooking something?

```
import pygame,sys,random, os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
#This One Works!!!!!!!


WINDOWHEIGHT = 1136
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
FPS = 40
TEXTCOLOR = (255,255,255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0,0,0)
PLAYERMOVEMENT = 6
HARVEYMOVEMENT = 5
TJMOVEMENT = 7
LASERMOVEMENT = 10
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 8
COLOR = 0
TJSIZE = 65
HARVEYSIZE = 65
#Check the sizes for these
def terminate():
    if pygame.event() == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

def startGame():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                return
def playerHasHitBaddies(playerRect,TjVirus,HarVirus):
    for b in TjVirus and HarVirus:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
        return False
def drawText(text,font,surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
WindowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
pygame.display.set_caption('Virus')




#Player Images

# Check the name of the .png file
TjImage = pygame.image.load('Virus_TJ_edited-1.png')
TjRect = TjImage.get_rect()
#chanhe this part from the baddies variable in the 'baddies' area
playerImage = pygame.image.load('Tank_RED.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
LaserImage = pygame.image.load('laser.png')
LaserRect = LaserImage.get_rect()

pygame.display.update()
startGame()



while True:

    TjVirus = []#the red one / make a new one for the blue one
    HarVirus = []#The BLue one / Need to create a new dictionary for this one
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = laser = False
    baddieAddCounter = 0




    while True:


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()


            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    lasers = True


                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if evnet.type == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    LaserImage.add(LaserRect)
                if event.key == ord('j'):
                    COLOR = 2
                if event.key == ord('k'):
                    if COLOR == 2:
                        COLOR = 1
                        playerImage = pygame.image.load('Tank_RED.png')
                    if COLOR == 1:
                        COLOR = 2
                        playerImage = pygame.image.load('Tank_BLUE.png')



            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieAddCounter = 0
#Dict for TJ(RED) VIRUS
            baddieSize = (TJSIZE)
            NewTjVirus = {'rect':pygame.Rect(random.rantint(0,WINDOWWIDTH - TJSIZE),0 - TJSIZE,TJSIZE,TJSIZE),
                         'speed':(TJMOVEMENT),
                         'surface':pygame.transform.scale(TJImage,(TJSIZE,TJSIZE)),
                         }
            TjVirus.append(NewTjVirus)

        #Dict for Harvey(BLUE) virus
            baddieSize = (HARVEYSIZE)
            NewHarveyVirus = {'rect':pygame.Rect(random.randint(0,WINDOWWIDTH - HARVEYSIZE),0 - HARVEYSIZE,HARVEYSIZE,HARVEYSIZE),
                              'speed':(HARVEYMOVEMENT),
                              'surface':pygame.transform.scale(HARVEYSIZE,(HARVEYSIZE,HARVEYSIZE))
                              }
            HarVirus.append(NewHarveyVirus)
#Player Movement
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left >0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1*PLAYERMOVEMENT,0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVEMENT,0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top >0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0,-1*PLAYERMOVEMENT)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0,PLAYERMOVEMENT)

            pygame,mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx,playerRect.centery)

            #Need to change for each individual virus
            for b in HarVirus and TjVirus:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0,b['speed'])

            for b in HarVirus and TjVirus:
                if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                    baddies.remove(b)


            windowSurface.fill(pygame.image.load('Background_Proto copy.png'))

        for b in HarVirus and TjVirus:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'],b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        if playerHasHitBaddies(playerRect,HarVirus,TjVirus):
                break
        for b in TjVirus and HarVirus[:]:
            if b['rect'].top < WINDOWHEIGHT:
                HarVirus.remove(b)
                TjVirus.remove(b)


        mainClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usally I use `pygame.display.flip()` not `pygame.display.update()`

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question! This answer is very short though and doesn't provide much context. Please explain some of the reasoning behind it, and it will become much more useful for the asker and future readers. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution, but it doesn't seem to work.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You call your `startGame()` in your script, which looks like this:

```
def startGame():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                return
```

The game is stuck in that `while` loop until you press a key.

---

That's your current problem, but there are other errors as well, like

```
def terminate():
    if pygame.event() == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
```

`pygame.event()` is not callable. Maybe you wanted to pass an event as argument here?

And also

```
pygame,mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx,playerRect.centery)
```

`,` instead of `.`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the quit module now works.  However, the game's still being stubborn and not running.  Could i be the Something I'm not seeing?